# Shell script to extract data from a file and store into another file as a csv

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a set of .html files within a folder and I'm trying to look through each folder and extract a particular bit of info and store it into a CSV file.

Each file contains a similar line of data:

```
<h1><span class='noScreen'>Intranet:<br/></span>CLAS1206: Web Infrastructure (2019-2020)</h1><div class='pageContentBars0'><hr class='hide'/>
```

I'm trying to take the CLAS plus the following 4 numbers (different for each file) and take the class name "Web Infrastructure" (again different for each file) get achieve the following:

```
CLAS1206, Web Infrastructure(\n)
CLAS1000, Mathematics(\n)
CLAS2000, Science(\n)
```

etc...

Thus far I've managed to use the sed command to remove everything before CLAS but I have no idea where to go from here. I have the following in my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep "<span class='noScreen'>" ./modules/CLAS1206.html | sed 's/^.*\(CLAS\)/\1/' | sed
```

which gives me the following output on the terminal

```
CLAS1206: Web Infrastructure (2019-2020)</h1><div class='pageContentBars0'><hr class='hide'/>
```

Any help on how to further break down this line and get it into the correct format would be appreciated!

Comment: A substitution with sed and a suitable regular expression should do the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would work around :

```
sed '/noScreen/ !d ; s/.*\(CLAS[0-9]\{4\}:\).*\(class=.*\).*/\1\2/ ; s/class=.//; s/.\/.*//'

francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ cat toto
<h1><span class='noScreen'>Intranet:<br/></span>CLAS1206: Web Infrastructure (2019-2020)</h1><div class='pageContentBars0'><hr class='hide'/>
<h1><span class='noScreen'>Intranet:<br/></span>CLAS1234: Web Infrastructure (2019-2020)</h1><div class='pageContentBars0'><hr class='testline2'/>
<h1><span class='noScreen'>Intranet:<br/></span>CLAS5678: Web Infrastructure (2019-2020)</h1><div class='pageContentBars0'><hr class='testline3'/>
francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ sed '/noScreen/ !d ; s/.*\(CLAS[0-9]\{4\}:\).*\(class=.*\).*/\1\2/ ; s/class=.//; s/.\/.*//' toto
CLAS1206:hide
CLAS1234:testline2
CLAS5678:testline3
francois@zaphod:~/tmp$
```

`/noScreen/ !d`  # grep the lines you need

`s/.*\(CLAS[0-9]\{4\}:\).*\(class=.*\).*/\1\2/`  # substrings CLASxxxx and class=

`s/class=.//; s/.\/.*//'` # substring to manage tailing chars

tips :
whenever it is possible (*maybe all the time*), choose only one language or tool for one action  (*do not use grep+sed+awk or even 2 of them*) keep your scripts simple

Comment: How does "sed '/noScreen/ !d" know which directory to look in? The files are located in a subfolder named "modules" 1 level deeper. Also I'm looking for 'CLAS1206,Web Infrastructure' not the :hide, sorry just trying to wrap my head around all the sed commands used

Comment: it uses the file path `sed 'commands' filepath/file`    it is a "grep" nothing else ; if you want to manage many directories & files you have to make a loop over the sed command  `for i in pathregexp ; do sed ........ $i  ; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmllint for parsing [xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath) nodes from your html file.

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath  '//h1/text()' file.html \
  | sed -r 's/(.*): (.*) \(.*\)/\1, \2/' > file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, mate : 
`filenames="1.html 2.html 3.html"; for filename in $filenames; do  grep  'pageContentBars0' $filename | sed 's/.*\(CLAS[^<\(]\+\).*/\1/' | sed 's/\:/,/'>>final.csv ; done`

I am assuming they all follow the same formatting, hence filtering initially using class pageContentBars0 : 
`grep  'pageContentBars0' $filename`

Here, I am looking for anything starting with CLAS, capture anything until `(` or `<` . 
`.*\(CLAS[^<\(]\+\)`

Ignore the rest of the bits and just replace the entire line with what was captured as the  *important bits* : 
`.*/\1`

Finally, replace `:` with `,` : 
`sed 's/\:/,/'`

Comment: The only issue I have with this method, is that I am searching through ~100 files, I don't really want to specify all ~100names. Is there a way to make filenames="*.html" or something along those lines?

Comment: sure mate.. you could do `filenames=$(find ./ -type f | grep html)`. Just make sure you put something specific in the grep and  the directory.

Comment: That's fine the folder literally only contains .html files that need to be searched through! I managed to get it working somewhat. Just for the last part "Finally, replace : with ," Am I able to replace ": " with ",". My output currently gives me "CLAS1206, Maths ". but I'd like to remove the space between the ", M". So "CLAS1206,Maths" is the output. Do I need to declare the space as its own special character using \?

Comment: Replace the last sed with this `sed 's/\: /,/'`